# Laravel 5.7 change custom config file in Controller?

Tags: php, configuration, global-variables, cart, laravel-5.7

I am about to program a small shop in Laravel 5.7. Currently, I have some trouble with passing the number of items that have been put to the cart to the header of my application. As I need this value as a global variable available to all routes and views, I've put it into a custom config file, **cartItems.php**. This is what it looks like:

```
return [
    'cartItems' => NULL
]
```

Now, whenever an item is pushed to the cart, I want to update that variable. This is done by the methos setCart in my **CartController**:

```
public function setCart (ValidateQtyForm $request)
{
    $cart = $this->setItems($request);   // trait where items are defined

    $cartItems = config('cartItems.cartItems');
    foreach ($cart as $item) {
        if ($item['amt'] >> 0) {
            $cartItems += $item['amt'];
        }
    }
    config(['cartItems.cartItems' => $cartItems]);
    return view('pages.cart', compact('cart'));
}
```

Then I can pull the number of cart items from the config file to my **header**:

```
<header>    
    <div id="cart">
        <a href="{!! route('cart') !!}">
            <figure>
                <img src="/img/layout/Einkaufswagen.svg">
            </figure>
            <div>{!! config('cartItems.cartItems') !!}</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Now this works fine so far for the cart view. 
But as soon as I go to another view of the Application (be it the shop page or the home page or whatever), the number of cart items is NULL again. 
Returning to the cart, it is still what it should be. 
It seems like the value in the config file is changed only in my cart view, but not in all my other views, right? **So how can I change this value and make the change accessible to all views?**

For the matter of completeness, here's my web.php file containing the routes:

```
// PAGES //

Route::get('/', 'AppController@showStart');
Route::get('/startseite', 'AppController@showStart')->name('start');
Route::view('/galerie', 'pages.gallery')->name('gallery');

// SHOP //
//*** Products ***//
Route::get('/items', 'ShopController@getShopItems');
Route::get('/shop', 'ShopController@showShopItems')->name('shop');
Route::post('/warenkorb', 'CartController@setCart')->name('set_qty');
//*** Cart***//
Route::get('/warenkorb', 'CartController@setCart')->name('cart');
Route::post('/bestellung', 'CartController@cartAction')->name('cart_post');
//*** Order ***//
Route::get('/bestellung', 'CartController@cartAction')->name('order_get');
Route::post('/abschluss', 'OrderController@orderProcessTransaction');
```

Thanks a lot, I appreciate any help with this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `session()` rather than `config()` (See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-session)). This will set the cart items for the current user's session.

The intention of the `config()` helper is to **override** configuration settings at runtime (e.g. database connection).

Using `config()` to save cart items is not recommended as it would mean that the next request to your application will not have the data set on the previous runtime.

Saving to session:

```
session(['cartItems' => $cartItems]);
```

To retrieve the session data:

```
session('cartItems');
```

Another point to make is that using laravel blade, you are able to set a **global variable** which can be used on all routes. This is done using [`View::composer`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers) and is recommended to be set within a service provider (e.g `appServiceProvider.php`) in the `->boot()` method:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('cartItems', session('cartItems'));
});
```